# Yepnope does not fire complete or callback when one file is already cached

Tags: javascript, jquery, yepnope, jquery-address

I'm using yepnope together with jQuery Address. In some yepnope calls, some files to be retrieved may already be loaded previously. However when that happens yepnope doesn't fire the complete or callback. How should i fix this?

```
yepnope({
load: ['/js_scripts/jquery.selectbox-0.2.min.js','/js_scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js','/js_scripts/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js','/css/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css','/js_scripts/search.js'],
    callback: {
        "search.js": function () {
            doSearch();
        }
    }
});
```

So basically i want it to work the same way as Query.getScript does. Always do the callback whether the retrieved file is downloaded or was already cached. Or maybe i should just use getScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by using LABjs instead. Through LABjs i can do:

```
$LAB
.script('/js_scripts/jquery.selectbox-0.2.min.js','/js_scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js','/js_scripts/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js','/js_scripts/search.js')
.wait(function(){ // wait for all scripts to execute first
    doSearch();
});
```

and it will always load. http://labjs.com/documentation.php

Comment: that's great. Whenever i got time i'll look into it. Problem with LAB is that it doesn't support css while yepnope does

Comment: I don't see the problem of lab not having any updates for two years though. when something works, there's no need to create updates just for the sake of doing it.